# What is the default properties that eclipse uses to launch a java process in its debugging mode?

Tags: java, eclipse, jdb

I would like to connect to java process started by eclipse  using a command line debugger but not sure what default properties of the eclipse launched java process are ? I wouldn't mind using attaching using sockets but not sure how much slower that would be ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about

```
-Xdebug -Xnoagent -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,suspend=n,address=localhost:12345
```

then you can attach a java debugger to port 12345

Comment: This doesn't answer the question: A Java program behaves differently depending on if it was started within Eclipse with "Run" or with "Debug"... so the question remains: What is the difference, command-option precisely?

Answer (score 0):

I investigated on the differences of Java application startup in Eclipse between "Run" and "Debug". I used Sysinternals' Process Explorer to see the command line of the java process that Eclipse forks when starting a Java application with either option. (I'm on a Windows 7 system)

With "Run HelloWorld"

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\bin\javaw.exe" -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 -classpath C:\workspace-juno\HelloWorld\bin com.example.HelloWorld
```

.......

With "Debug HelloWorld"

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\bin\javaw.exe" -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,suspend=y,address=localhost:2404 -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 -classpath C:\workspace-juno\HelloWorld\bin com.example.HelloWorld
```

(The address port changed in succeeding invocations, e.g. it became `address=localhost:2564` at the next invocation.)
So java (or javaw) actually gets started with different options depending on whether "Run" or "Debug" was used: the "Debug" start-up adds an additional `agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,suspend=y,address=localhost:NNNN` option. This is a standard way of putting a JVM into debuggable mode. The HelloWorld program will first wait for its debugger to successfully connect to it before continuing (option `suspend=y`). The HelloWorld JVM will connect itself automatically to some debugger running on address localhost:NNNN (... option `address=localhost:NNNN` and implicit default option `server=n`). (... [Oracle provides authoritative information on the `agentlib` start-up options](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/conninv.html))

Eclipse itself will act as the debugger application providing a port NNNN. The HelloWorld JVM will connect to this port, via its own port of number NNNN+1 (one can see a process's used ports with Process Explorer on that process's TCP/IP tab).